# .NET Framework : Silverlight and DAL connection

Tags: .net, silverlight, data-access-layer

I tried to connect my DAL (Data Access Layer) with my BL (Business Layer) in Silverlight, but I didn't find any simple example on the internet.

Please, someone can help me, I'm a beginner with the .NET Framework and I'm really lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a WebService to connect your C# Dal with your Silverlight presentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've got found a tutorial with your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a WebService in C# like in this tutorial : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112470/Developing-a-REST-Web-Service-using-C-A-walkthroug

Comment: Wao, this tutorial is totally complete!
Thanks you too!